# Parent (Primary Key) to the Child(Foreign Key) object using hibernate never gets set

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

The parent PK is not being set as the FK for the child during the `INSERT` operation.

Here is the error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column
>   "workout_id" violates not-null constraint
>
> Detail: Failing row contains (20ea52e3-0491-480f-b3c1-b1da70feee8f,
>   null, null, 510, 55, KG, Olympic).

In this case, only one ID is generated, and that is for the child. The parent ID is never created, and thus the FK constraint is broken and the DB transaction fails.

To troubleshoot this issue, I removed the child from the parent, and a `UUID` is indeed generated for the parent.

In the example below, `Workout` is the parent, and `Set` is the child. Also shown is the endpoint where the persistence operation is executed.

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "workouts")
public class Workout implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long user; // todo use UUID

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "workout")
    //@JoinColumn(columnDefinition="uuid", name = "workout_id")
    private List<Set> set;


    @Column(name="start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name="stop_time")
    private String stopTime;

    @Column(name="notes")
    private String notes;
}


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercise_sets")
public class Set {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="workout_id")
    private Workout workout;

    @Column(name="reps")
    private Integer numberOfReps;

    @Column(name="weight")
    private Integer weightLifted;

    @Column(name="unit")
    private String  weightUnit;

    @Column(name="bar_type")
    private String barType;

}

@RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> addWorkoutForUser(@PathVariable(name="id") long id) {        
        Set s = Set.builder()
                //.workout(w)
                //.workoutId(1)
                .numberOfReps(10)
                .weightLifted(25)
                .weightUnit("KG")
                .barType("Olympic").build();

        Set s2 = Set.builder()
                //.workout(w)
                //.workoutId(1)
                .numberOfReps(510)
                .weightLifted(55)
                .weightUnit("KG")
                .barType("Olympic").build();

        Workout w = Workout.builder()
                .set(Arrays.asList(s2,s))
                .name("My First Workout")
                .notes("Felt great")
                .startTime("now")
                .stopTime("later").build();

        Workout persistedData = this.workoutDao.save(w);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(persistedData);
    }
```

Comment: And the rest of your code?

Comment: original code sample is now updated.

Comment: Ok you most certainly have to set the "workout" on your "sets". Before saving call `s1.setWorkout(w); s2.setWorkout(w);`

Comment: This did indeed do the trick. Thanks